# Installing previous versions of QGIS on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, repository

I have been doing some work with QGIS 3.12 Bucaresti. For some reason I had to reboot the computer so I installed QGIS again. However, the official QGIS repository is now installing a newer version (QGIS 3.16 Hannover). With this newer version the previous work I did is not working. Tried also 3.18 Zürich but no luck either.

The work is a code that connects a software with QGIS to send data from one to another, I mean, it is not a particular fixture that provides QGIS by default.

I have been searching and I found this https://qgis.org/downloads/ which saves previous versions of QGIS. However I have not managed yet to properly installed QGIS 3.12.

Wondering if anyone has done it before or knows what steps I should follow to install previous versions of QGIS on Ubuntu.

Comment: How are you installing QGIS? Via apt? What other versions are available from the repositories you have active? Try: `apt show qgis -a | grep Version` and show us the output....

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,

I am installing via apt following the steps provided on their official website (https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). There are currently three:
- 3.16 Hannover via this repository: deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
- 3.18 Zurich via this repository: deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis bionic main
- 2.18 Las Palmas via this repository: deb     https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main and using a key from 2017 (wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import)

Comment: The output for apt show qgis -a | grep Version is:

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.  

Version: 1:3.16.3+28bionic  
Version: 2.18.17+dfsg-1

Comment: I already sorted out installing QGIS from source. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Ubuntugis unstable ppa without adding the QGIS repo, you can get currently

qgis version 3.10.12+dfsg-1~bionic1

Apart from that, you should still have the downloaded packages from your previous install, unless you did a autoremove.

Answer (score 0):

Use Conda to install previous versions of QGIS. The recipe below considers you already installed miniconda that provides the `conda` command line utility (recipe https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html)

```bsh
# Configure to add conda-forge as Conda repo
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict

# Create env
conda create --name qgis_312 -y
# Activate env
conda activate qgis_312

# Search available 3.12 versions to get exact subversion
conda search qgis --channel conda-forge |grep 3.12
conda install qgis=3.12.2 --channel conda-forge -y

# Create dir for QGIS configuration (to avoid conflict with other QGIS versions)
mkdir $HOME/qgis_312
# Launch QGIS
qgis --profiles-path $HOME/qgis_312

# When you do not need QGIS 3.12 anymore for today
conda deactivate
```

Each time you need to use 3.12, do

```bsh
conda activate qgis_312
qgis --profiles-path $HOME/qgis_312
```

Comment: Do you know why this is not possible with qgis 3.20 or newer versions?

Comment: Because too many dependencies not updated on the conda side to be able to build recent QGIS versions. See the issue https://github.com/conda-forge/qgis-feedstock/pull/194#issuecomment-1066027450